# Reading and writing a jpg-file with GD-library

Tags: php, gd

I used images as BLOB out of a DB for further processing with Imagick.
But now I need to use image-files to do the same thing.

I've some problems to convert my "old" script for using files. I changed it to `imageCreateFromJpeg` (for reading source-file) and `imagejpeg()` (for writing the image-file). But it doesn't work.
But the source-file isn't updated. What am I doing wrong?

```
$image = ImageCreateFromString(base64_decode($file->source));
$image_width = imagesx($image);
$image_height = imagesy($image);

/* Do some processing
some... ImageCreateTrueColor(...);

ImageCopy(...);
ImageCopyResized(...);
ImageCopyMerge(...);
*/

ob_start();
imagejpeg($image, NULL, 100);
$processed_image = base64_encode(ob_get_contents());
imagedestroy($image);
ob_end_clean();
```

I changed it to this:

```
$file = 'path/to/image.jpg';
$image = imageCreateFromJpeg($file); // read from file
$image_width = imagesx($image);
$image_height = imagesy($image);

/* Do some processing
some... ImageCreateTrueColor(...);

ImageCopy(...);
ImageCopyResized(...);
ImageCopyMerge(...);
*/

ob_start();
imagejpeg($image, $file, 100); // write everthing to the same file
imagedestroy($image);
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example (incl. resize - set your values for destination `$width` and `$height`):

```
    list($originalWidth, $originalHeight) = getimagesize($file);
    $src  = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    ImageCopyResampled($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($dest);
    $size = ob_get_length();
    header("Content-Length: " . $size);
    ob_end_flush();
    imagedestroy($dest);
    exit;
```